# np.select instead of for while loop

Tags: python, performance, numpy, for-loop

I am aiming to dramatically speed up my code which I think can be done using np.select although I dont know how.

Here is a the current output of the when my code is executed:

```
date  starting_temp  average_high  average_low  limit_temp observation_date   Date_Limit_reached
2019-12-03 22:30:00 NaN             13.0          14.8        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-03 23:00:00 NaN             14.7          14.9        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-03 23:30:00 NaN             13.0          13.9        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 00:00:00  13.2           13.0          14.7        NaN                          2019-12-04 10:00:00
2019-12-04 00:30:00 NaN             14.0          13.8        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 01:00:00 NaN             13.9          13.8        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 01:30:00 NaN             13.6          14.8        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 02:00:00 NaN             13.1          14.5        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 02:30:00 NaN             14.9          13.7        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 03:00:00 NaN             14.2          14.1        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 03:30:00 NaN             13.4          14.1        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 04:00:00 NaN             14.3          13.0        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 04:30:00 NaN             13.5          14.1        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 05:00:00 NaN             13.6          13.4        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 05:30:00 NaN             14.5          13.9        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 06:00:00 NaN             14.4          14.5        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 06:30:00 NaN             13.7          14.2        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 07:00:00 NaN             13.7          14.2        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 07:30:00 NaN             13.2          14.4        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 08:00:00 NaN             13.9          13.1        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 08:30:00 NaN             13.9          14.4        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 09:00:00 NaN             14.4          13.9        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 09:30:00 NaN             14.4          13.8        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 10:00:00 NaN             15.0          14.0        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 10:30:00 NaN             13.2          13.2        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 11:00:00 NaN             14.0          13.3        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 11:30:00 NaN             14.2          13.4        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 12:00:00 NaN             14.2          13.4        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 12:30:00 NaN             13.7          13.6        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 13:00:00 NaN             14.1          13.3        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 13:30:00 NaN             13.1          14.1        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 14:00:00 NaN             13.2          14.3        NaN                          nan                
2019-12-04 14:30:00 NaN             13.7          13.8        NaN                          nan
```

The code to produce the final df['Date_Limit_reached'] column is way too slow which I have added below. I would like to change its structure to `np.select` if possible:

```
    new_col = []
    
    df_size = len(df)
    
    # Loop the dataframe
    for ind in df.index:
        if not math.isnan(df['starting_temp'][ind]):   
            entry_price_val = df['starting_temp'][ind]
            count = 0
            hasValue = False
    
            while count < df_size:
       
                if df['starting_temp'][ind] > df['limit_temp'][ind] and df['limit_temp'][ind] >= df['asklow'][count] and df['date'][count] >= df['observation_date'][ind] :
                    new_col.append(df['date'][count])
                    hasValue = True
                    break  # Break the loop if matching value meets
                    count += 1
    
                elif df['starting_temp'][ind] < df['limit_temp'][ind] and df['limit_temp'][ind] <= df['average_high'][count] and df['date'][count] >= df['observation_date'][ind] :
                    new_col.append(df['date'][count])
                    hasValue = True
                    break  # Break the loop if matching value meets
                count += 1            
    
            # If matching value not meets, then append nan value to the column   
            if not hasValue:
                new_col.append(float('nan'))
        else:
            new_col.append(float('nan'))
    
 
   df['Date_Limit_reached'] = new_col
```

Comment: What is `df`? It's not defined in the code.

Comment: Can you provide a code that create the sample dataframe `df` so we can easily agree on column types, test your code and talk about performance on similar data?

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't run the code due lack of df here my suggestions:

- use less flags but concrete values instead. makes the code more readable. hasValue --> val
- you will have a problem if there is an entry with `df['starting_temp'][ind] == df['limit_temp'][ind]` because none of your cases will fire. Maybe this is the problem with the slow code.
- you can pre-calculate the first boolean expression in the while loops. This might solve the issue from the above point
- you don't use `entry_price_val`
- for further improvement use vectorization of your data, this is possible in all of the loops. (not shown in my code since I can't test it)

here is my suggested code

```
new_col = []
df_size = len(df)    
for ind in df.index:
    val = float('nan') # use data instead of flags
    
    if not math.isnan(df['starting_temp'][ind]):   
        count = 0
        
        if df['starting_temp'][ind] > df['limit_temp'][ind]:
            while count < df_size:
                if df['limit_temp'][ind] >= df['asklow'][count] and df['date'][count] >= df['observation_date'][ind] :
                    val=df['date'][count]
                    break  # Break the loop if matching value meets
                count += 1  
        elif df['starting_temp'][ind] < df['limit_temp'][ind]
            while count < df_size:
                if df['limit_temp'][ind] <= df['average_high'][count] and df['date'][count] >= df['observation_date'][ind] :
                    val = df['date'][count]
                    break  # Break the loop if matching value meets
                count += 1            
    new_col.append(val)
df['Date_Limit_reached'] = new_col
```

Code snippets were not tested, test for correctness required, further improvements possible (hints on request).